# Gardening problem - mass planting in a circular area

Tags: packing-problem

First of all I am not a mathematician, forgive me if this is a stupid question.

A circular area is given. How to place n plants within the area so that the minimal distance between any of two plants is maximized?

I would truly appreciate some visual answers for cases n up to 50.

Comment: Can't understand the phrase '... so that minimal distance between any of two plants is maximised ?'

Comment: @AnikBhowmick That is, the points are "as evenly spaced as possible". The phrase is unambiguous: $\max(\min_{x,y} |x-y|)$.

Comment: Okay... Understandable in mathematical terms. Thanks !!

Comment: @Patrick You are correct.

Comment: Please, write a more informative title.

Comment: You know the answer for 7 points. Suggest you try to go from there.

Comment: I think the question is equivalent to putting 50 identical small circles inside a big circle and find the largest radius of the small circle.

Comment: You could also phrase it as: so that the distance between the two closest plants is maximized.

Comment: This site gives you an answer and draws you a picture. https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/smaller-circles-in-larger-circle-d_1849.html

Comment: Place the plants at the centers of the black disks shown here: [Circle packing in a circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_in_a_circle). For up to 2600 plants, see [Packomania](http://hydra.nat.uni-magdeburg.de/packing/cci/) (click the number in the left column for a picture, for example [50](http://hydra.nat.uni-magdeburg.de/packing/cci/cci50.html)).

Comment: Many of the comments above are helpful (especially Rahul's). But it seems to me that everyone has forgotten that the question does not constrain the packed smaller circles to be totally within the large circle --- only their centers need to be. So don't forget when using the above tools to increase the diameter of the large circle by your minimal distance (i.e., the diameter of the smaller circles).

Comment: @RonKaminsky Good point. Actually excellent point! I can increase the diameter of the large circle - but with not yet known small radius?? What guaranties that the optimal solution for circle packing is also the optimal solution for plant packing? I am not convinced.

Comment: @Ron, Aleksandar: The solution to the packing problem gives you the largest radius $r$ such that $n$ circles will fit into a unit circle. Then the centers of the circles are at least a distance $2r$ from each other and at least $r$ from the boundary of the unit circle. Scale all the center coordinates by $1-r$, and you have $n$ points in a unit circle as far apart as possible and with no gap from the unit circle.

Comment: @Rahul Consider two circle packings into unit circle yielding r_1 and r_2 smaller circle radiuses, and r_1>r_2. You have to scale them by factors 1/(1-r_1) and 1/(1-r_2) to transform them to plant packings. Resulting plant packing smaller circle radiuses will be r_1/(1-r_1) and r_2/(1-r_2).  Since  r_1/(1-r_1) > r_2/(1-r_2), packing 1 is better. Is this a correct proof of equivalence of circle and plant packing problems?